# Problem with simplemodal jQuery

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I use this call to create modal window using simplemodal (http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/):

```
$.get("openform/", function(data){
    $.modal(data, {
        closeHTML:'<a class="modalCloseImg simplemodal-close" title="Close"/>',
        minHeight:400,
        autoResize:'True',
        });
    });
```

The html output is fairly simple. Among the data is empty div -

```
<div id="errors"></div>
```

The problem is that, button in the same form does ajax call and fills #errors with errormessages and the simplemodal wrapper does not autoResize. Even calling

```
$.modal.resize();
```

does nothing.

Edit:
The call that fills #errors is this:

```
$("#addk").live("click", function(event){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "savenow/",
        data: $("#form").serialize(), 
        success: function(msg){
            $("#errors").html(msg);
            $.modal.resize();
        },
        error : function(){
            $("#errors").html(<p>Fail!</p>);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Using live there because the button too comes from previous ajax call.

Am i doing something wrong? Is there a way to get this working without my own function for resizing the window?

Alan

Comment: try using True as lowercase.  The plugin may not be properly parsing booleans.

Comment: Thanks, but it did not change anything.

Comment: Removing minHeight option does not change anything either. The size set for window without min height is even smaller than 400px that i have set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following error function in the ajax call:

```
error : function(){
                $("#errors").html("<p>Fail!</p>");
                $(".simplemodal-container").css("height", "auto");
        }
```

Comment: Had a similar issue with the container not resizing on content change. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

first (and this is not the root of your troubles): `'True'` and `'true'` are strings, as are `'False'` and `'false'`.  All these strings are "truish" in boolean contexts.

second: a quick peek in the source of simplemodal 1.3.3 reveals that `autoResize` kicks in only when the browser window is resized, which is not your case at all.